# Angular2 - Validators.compose

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am having problems with the `Validators.compose` function (no errors, just doesn't validate)

Here is my code:

```
  var validators = ()=> {
           var validatorArr = [];                
           validatorArr.push(Validators.required);
           validatorArr.push(Validators.maxLength(column.max));
           return Validators.compose(validatorArr);
    };
  var ctrl: Control = new Control(row.items[column.mapper], validators);
  row.form.addControl(column.mapper, ctrl);
```

when I put `Validators.required` instead of the `validators` function, the validation works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use this code rather and not use a callback to define your validators:

```
var validatorArr = [];                
validatorArr.push(Validators.required);
validatorArr.push(Validators.maxLength(column.max));

var ctrl: Control = new Control(row.items[column.mapper], 
                   Validators.compose(validatorArr));
row.form.addControl(column.mapper, ctrl);
```

The second parameter of the `Control` constructor correspond to a function that can be created using the `compose` method...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Validators.compose(validatorArr)`?

Comment: Mr. Thierry Templier, I really appreciate your help. Thank you. (I wrote my code like that the first time around, but the typescript went mad about "type any[]", so now I firstly declare the variable as null, and then set it to an array

Answer (score 1):

Just use it without arrow function:

```
new Control(row.items[column.mapper],Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]));
```

or

```
var validators = ()=> {
     return Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]);
}

new Control(row.items[column.mapper], validators());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in the end the problem was purely typescript. I removed the validators function entirely and use Validators.compose(arrayOfValidators) directly;

Answer (score 1):

The Control constructor expects a `ValidatorFn` as argument. `Validators.compose()` takes an array of `ValidatorFn` and returns one `ValidatorFn`. But you're not passing that `ValidatorFn` as argument. You're passing a function which, when called, returns a `ValidatorFn`.

Replace your code by

```
var validatorArr = [];                
validatorArr.push(Validators.required);
validatorArr.push(Validators.maxLength(column.max));
var validatorFn = Validators.compose(validatorArr);

var ctrl: Control = new Control(row.items[column.mapper], validatorFn);
row.form.addControl(column.mapper, ctrl);
```

Or, shorter:

```
var ctrl: Control = new Control(row.items[column.mapper], 
                                Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
                                                    Validators.maxLength(column.max)]));
row.form.addControl(column.mapper, ctrl);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
the whole problem for me started at line 1 - typescript complained that validatorArr is of type any[] and is not allowed inside compose.
I bypassed that by `
 var validatorArr;
                        validatorArr=[];`